# Delete records where one attribute equals other in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

looking to delete the records when two attributes of same table are same (%k1 = %k2).

Example in table User, delete records which has User.firstName == User.lastName.
Note NSPredicate(format: "firstName != lastName") does not help even to fetch records.

Looks a kind of self join, which not the way core data works, but have some requirement to delate such records in same table. Any help in predicate please

Comment: "Does not help" - does it throw an error, or fetch nothing, or fetch everything?

Comment: fetches all records to delete..

Comment: That predicate fetches instances where they're not equal. You want where they *are* equal, right?

Comment: need of some way to delete the records where two attributes are equal..

Answer (score 0):

- Fetch **all** data.
- Filter `let duplicates = users.filter { $0.firstName == $0.lastName }`.
- Delete the found items.

Comment: looking for deleting records with kind of nspredicate... not to filter the data before or after fetch...

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that with a predicate